# Django UnicodeDecodeError While inserting arabic letters

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to input Arabic letters while using django command `python manage.py createsuperuser`

and it gives me always this error, what should i do to solve this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mohammed/PycharmProjects/PatientStatus/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mohammed/PycharmProjects/PatientStatus/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/mohammed/PycharmProjects/PatientStatus/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/mohammed/PycharmProjects/PatientStatus/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 61, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/mohammed/PycharmProjects/PatientStatus/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/mohammed/PycharmProjects/PatientStatus/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 111, in handle
    input_value = self.get_input_data(field, message)
  File "/home/mohammed/PycharmProjects/PatientStatus/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 176, in get_input_data
    raw_value = input(message)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 4: invalid continuation byte
```